# Rails Enumerated Types or Alternatives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I'm just learning ruby on rails and I have a table of user roles (Owner, Admin, and User).  There are going to be places in the code where I need to check the user's role and show different options.  Does anyone know how to do this without resorting to magic numbers or other ugly methods?

In ASP.Net web apps I've worked on I've seen this done through the use of enumerated types:

```
public enum UserRole { Owner = 1, Admin = 2, User = 3 }

// ...

if (user.Role == UserRole.Admin)
    // Show special admin options
```

Each different role in the database is reflected as an enumerated type with a value set to the ID of that role in the database.  That doesn't seem like a very good solution because it depends on knowledge of database that may change.  Even if it is the proper way to handle something like this, I don't know how to use enumerated types in rails.

I would appreciate any insight into this matter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ruby itself does not have an enumerated type, but this site shows a method http://www.rubyfleebie.com/enumerations-and-ruby/

You could make something like this in your User model:

```
#constants
OWNER = 1
ADMIN = 2
USER = 3

def is_owner?
  self.role == OWNER
end

def is_admin?
  self.role == ADMIN
end

def is_user?
  self.role == USER
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Could the functionality added in Rails 4.1, be what you are looking for ?

http://coherence.io/blog/2013/12/17/whats-new-in-rails-4-1.html

Copy from blog post:

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relevant schema change looks like this:
  #
  # create_table :bugs do |t|
  #   t.column :status, :integer, default: 0 # defaults to the first value (i.e. :unverified)
  # end

  enum status: [ :unverified, :confirmed, :assigned, :in_progress, :resolved, :rejected, :reopened ]

...

Bug.resolved           # => a scope to find all resolved bugs
bug.resolved?          # => check if bug has the status resolved
bug.resolved!          # => update! the bug with status set to resolved
bug.status             # => a string describing the bug's status
bug.status = :resolved # => set the bug's status to resolved
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a really good case for using my [classy_enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) gem. It essentially allows you to define a fixed set of options, where each one is a class with behavior and properties specific to it. It helps cut down on all the conditional logic that tends to get scattered throughout the application.

For example, If you are doing things like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def options
    if user.is_admin?
      [...admin options...]
    else
      [...non admin options...]
    end
  end
end
```

Then calling as: `user.options` somewhere else...

classy_enum allows you to move that logic to a separate place and have the same functionality with no conditional logic:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  classy_enum_attr :role

  delegate :options, :to => :role
end
```

The [README](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum/blob/master/README.md) has a working example and describes the gem in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the aptly named [Authorization](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/tree/master/) plugin for situations like this.

This will let you

```
permit "role"
```

to restrict access to roles, and

```
permit? "role"
```

to simply test for access.  Both of these delegate to `User#has_role?(role)`.

Don't feel like you have to use their `ObjectRoles` implementation.  You can use the `Hardwired` roles and then implement your own `User#has_role?(role)` method to use your existing schema.

Comment: Also, Ryan Bates has a good Authorization gem called cancan and a nice tutorial on his site (http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)

Answer (score 2):

Just starting to learn Rails (from C#), and had this exact same question. It seems that Rails doesn't really have enums because the philosophy is different. I would use tons of enums to try to organize all the details in a C# project, but maybe since Rails handles so much for you they aren't that important. It's not really an answer, just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [enum plugin](http://enum-column.rubyforge.org/) on rubyforge so you do:

```
t.column :severity, :enum, :limit => [:low, :medium, :high, :critical]
```

It's pretty ugly to use `:limit` attribute to pass parameters, but it's a more standardized way.

To install just do:

```
script/plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/enum-column/plugins/enum-column
```

it currenctly works with Rails 2.2.2 or later. 
Rubyforge link: www.rubyforge.org/projects/enum-column/